# Xaml align text and image within button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 buttons with an image and text inside:

```
<Button Height="70" Background="#FF2A303E" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5,0,0,0">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Width="48" Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                <Path Data="M10,20V14H14V20H19V12H22L12,3L2,12H5V20H10Z" Fill="White" />
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
        <Label Margin="50, 5" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei UI Light" Foreground="White">Berichte</Label>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Everything works fine but I am not able to align the image on the left side of the button. I want the grid inside the button to take up the full inner space but it looks like this instead:

[image]

This is an issue because if the labels inside the button are not of the same size, it looks kind of weird because the icons aren't in one symmetrical line.

Comment: it seems like you have to override template not just content for button

Comment: btw, there is a [WPF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) chat room

Comment: Perfect, the other question you provided worked out. Sorry, I didn't find the other question before, my bad. Thanks anyway. @FoggyFinder

Comment: Glad to heard it. Sometimes it is really hard to find something therefore I advise closing question instead of remove it.